# dotnet 6 Run "ng serve" independently

Tags: angular, single-page-application, asp.net-core-6.0

In .NET 3.1 angular SPA template, we are able to run angular angular server independently by setting configuration in the startup to like

`spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");`

Now I'm creating an angular SPA project in .Net core 6 and I need to run angular independently from MSBuild to avoid restarting the angular server every time I rebuild

How could this be accomplished!?

Answer (score 0):

what I wanted to do is to avoid restarting angular every time I rebuild my backend, this is very time-consuming and I was able to achieve that as follow:

1. open .csproj file and comment line: `<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>`
2. At  file `proxy.conf.json` ensure that the target value is the same URL & port of the backend (I made it static to be clear)
3. run the backend first then manually run `npm start` at the client project root

Answer (score 0):

seems like spa things are on package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions", so you have to add it. Then you can code:

```
app.UseSpa(config => config.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:44434"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you created a new project in Visual Studio using the ASP.NET Core app with Angular template ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022)), then just search for the "npm" string in its .csproj  files. You'll find something like this:

```
   <Project>
     <!-- ...other lines -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
        <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
        <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
        <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

   </Project>
```

Remove the nodes containing '`npm`' and that should fix it.

However, since what you're trying to achieve is being able to run the Angular app independently, I think you're approaching this the wrong way. The whole point of the MS SPA templates is to offer you an integrated experience where you don't have to worry about things like `npm install` or `npm serve`. If you want to take control over that, you would be better off just adding your Angular app in a new project in your VS solution.

Comment: did you try this solution!!?, I think this will break the app.

Comment: Yes, this is how I made it work in a previous version of the template. However, I don't think this is how you should approach this - see my updated comment.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I do want to be integrated, but I just want to avoid restarting angular server in development time to save time

Comment: Doing this won't break much, but it also won't help with keeping the Angular server from restarting. The first node that would be removed is an `npm install` which wouldn't cause the Angular server to restart, even if it did run. However, if you notice the Target that it's in has a condition of `!Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules')`, so it will only run if `npm install` hasn't already been run.  The other nodes are inside a Target that is set to `AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish"`, so they will only be run on Publish, not Build.